# Which byte is loaded from memory in this MIPS code?

Tags: byte, mips, endianness

Consider the following code:

```
lbu $t0, 0($t1)

sw $t0, 0($t2)
```

Assume that the register `$t1` contains the address 0x1000 0000 and the register
`$t2` contains the address 0x1000 0010. Note the MIPS architecture utilizes
big-endian addressing. Assume that the data (in hexadecimal) at address 0x1000
0000 is: 0x11223344. What value is stored at the address pointed to by register
$t2?

My question is, will the lbu instruction load the most significant byte, 0x11, or the least significant, 0x44?  I saw an image on wikipedia that says 8 bit memory access occurs from the right to the left, so I am slightly confused, since the address should point to the MSB in a big endian machine.

Here is a link to the picture
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#mediaviewer/File:Endianessmap.svg

Comment: There's another image on the same wikipedia page that I think makes it clear: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#mediaviewer/File:Big-Endian.svg

Answer (score 4):

$t2value = 0x0000 0011

big-endian format in memory
(high)
44
33
22
11
(low)

Because the MIPS processor uses Big Endian addressing (i.e. a word is stored starting
with its most significant byte, or its “big end”), the word 0x11223344 would be
stored as four consecutive bytes: 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, and 0x44 at addresses 0x1000 0000,
0x1000 0001, 0x1000 0002, and 0x1000 0003, respectively.
Executing the lbu instruction results in loading the byte stored at address 0x1000 0000
and storing it in the least significant 8-bits of register $t0. In other words, after executing
this instruction, the contents of register $t0 will be: 0x00000011. This is the same
32-bit word that will get stored in memory after executing the sw instruction.